# Unable to start Selenium server using WebdriverIO on Windows

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

I'm following instructions from http://webdriver.io/guide.html

The fourth step mentions this:

`java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar`

After downloading and installing `Selenium` and `WebdriverIO` for Windows, I provided the environmental path for all the drivers and executables in System Properties.

I seem to be hitting this issue after I try to execute the aforementioned command through `Powershell`.

```
PS C:\webdriverio-test> java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=".\geckodriver.exe" .\selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile .gecko.driver=.\geckodriver.exe
PS C:\webdriverio-test> java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe .\selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile .gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe
PS C:\webdriverio-test> java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver .\selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile .gecko.driver=geckodriver 
PS C:\webdriverio-test> java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver .\selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile .gecko.driver=./geckodriver
```

If I try running standalone `Selenium` server without using `geckodriver`, it works well. However, the main intention is to make it work using `geckodriver` and something seems to be going wrong here.

It just worked once when I installed it yesterday, but it doesn't seem to be working now. Any pointers as to how to make this work, would be appreciable.

Contents of the directory:

```
PS C:\webdriverio-test> ls


    Directory: C:\webdriverio-test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        5/31/2018   2:41 PM                node_modules
d-----        5/31/2018  10:54 AM                nssm-2.24
d-----        5/31/2018  10:40 AM                test
-a----         4/8/2018  12:49 PM        9684296 geckodriver.exe
-a----        5/31/2018   2:41 PM          50430 package-lock.json
-a----        5/30/2018   3:37 PM       23556263 selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
-a----        5/30/2018   4:16 PM            383 test.js
-a----        5/31/2018   9:31 AM            471 test_2.js
-a----        5/31/2018  10:51 AM           9875 wdio.conf.js
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar file must follow the `-jar`, noting allowed to insert between `-jar` and the jar file

**Execute in Windows CMD：**

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver.exe -jar ./selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
```

**Execute in Windows PowerShell:**

```
java "-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver_2.38.exe" -jar .\selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
```

For PowerShell, if the name of `-Dname=value` includes `.`, you must use double quote to around the `-Dname=value`

**Note**: please use JDK 8 or above.

Comment: Throws an error like this: 

`PS C:\webdriverio-test> java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./geckodriver -jar .\selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class .gecko.driver=..geckodriver`

Comment: Thank you.. 
There seems to be an issue when I execute this command through `Powershell`. I see the same error noted before in my comment. However, the same command seems to work well in `cmd`. Hence, I've accepted and upvoted your answer. 
Thanks again..

Comment: To make sure I'm not missing anything, I just copy-pasted the command that you provided. So, there's no problem with the whitespace. Is there a way I can make this work on `Powershell`? I would also like to understand as to what could be the reason for this command to work only on `cmd`.